# How to get required nuget package when building C# project in Azure pipeline?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I was building a C# project in Azure pipeline and got following error. I resolved it by uploaded the required Blend package to the GitHub repository. Supposing I don't want to put these Nuget packages in GitHub repo, what command should I use to let the pipeline to download the required packages automatically when pipeline started building ? Thanks.

```
Error MC3074: The tag 'Interaction.Behaviors' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors'. Line 239 Position 26.


<Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Expression.Blend.Sdk.1.0.2\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
<Private>True</Private>
```

Comment: If you are in your DevOps "Edit Pipeline" Page and you have the "Tasks" open: Scroll down to Task "NuGet - **Restore**, pack or push NuGet packages, or run ..." - Add it and configure to your needs.

Comment: In my pipeline Yaml it appears as `task: DotNetCorCLI@2   inputs: command: 'restore'`

Comment: Did your issue resolve with the above suggestions?